# How to create new method into existing WCF services?

Tags: c#, wcf, model-view-controller

I have one existing **WCF** services project. I want to create new method as per my new requirement. How can I create new method inside my **WCF** service? Also I want to access the database through a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Is it an OperationContract method? Just add the new method...there isn't extremely difficult about it. Do you have any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new `OperationContract` into your `ServiceContract` like:

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool DoSomething(string param);
}
```

and implement the method then in the `ServiceBehavior`:

```
[ServiceBehavior()]
public class MyService
    : IMyService
{
    public bool DoSomething(string param)
    {
       //Do Something....
    }
}
```

or in MVC add an new method to your `ApiController` like:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
 {
        [Route("api/DoSomething/")]
        [HttpGet]
        public bool DoSomething(string param)
        {
             //Do Something...
        }
  }
```

Maybe you can show some of your code ...

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that.